# How to limit Ant InputNumber maxLength

Tags: reactjs, next.js, input, antd, maxlength

I am using antd InputNumber component. I wanted to set the maxLength but it doesn't work . I also tried to do it with max attribute to limit the charachters at 12. But none of them worked.

```
                 <InputNumber
                     required
                    type="number"
                    addonBefore="+"
                    defaultValue={994}
                    controls={false}
                    value={combinedState?.phoneNumber}
                    onChange={(e)=>  setCombinedState((prevState: any) => ({
                        ...prevState,
                        phoneNumber: e,
                      }));}
                    onKeyDown={(event) => {
                      if (
                        event.key == 'e' ||
                        event.key == '+' ||
                        event.key == '-' ||
                        event.key == '.'
                      ) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                      }
                    }}
                    onInput={(e) => {
                      if (e.length > 4) {
                        console.log('s');
                      }
                    }}
                    min={0}
                    max={999999999999}
                  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using the onChange event handler of the input to stop the user from entering more than the desired amount of characters:

```
interface Props extends InputNumberProps {
  maxLength?: number;
}

export default function MyInput(props: Props): JSX.Element {
  const { onChange, maxLength = -1, ...rest } = props;

  const handleChange = useCallback((e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const value = e.currentTarget.value.toString();
    if (value.length === maxLength) return;
    onChange?.(e);
  }, [onChange, maxLength]);

  return <InputNumber {...rest} onChange={handleChange} />;
}

export type { Props as MyInputProps };
```

Please note that you should do some research on your own before posting to stack overflow. A look at the antd component documentation [here](https://ant.design/components/input-number#api) would've probably sufficed.

Comment: As you can see I already tried that method in my code. I set `min` to 0 and `max` to 999999999999 so that it will be 12 characters long. But it didn't work and I did some research , tried other methods as slicing method and setting it to inputs value on onchane but nothing worked. I would appreciate if you would look at my code carefully and recomment solutions.

Comment: @KonulMemmedova Check the answer again.